# How do I link a container in docker only if it exists when starting the container?

Tags: nginx, docker

In a server, I currently have many HTTP-applications running which would share port 80, so I have one main nginx container that routes to the specific apps on a hostname basis (reverse proxy).

However, when I `docker start nginx`, all those containers must be running, because I linked all of them when I `run` the nginx container for the first time. This creates a single bottleneck, so if one of my applications goes down, I cannot `start` the main nginx:

`Error response from daemon: Cannot start container nginx: Cannot link to a non running container: /myapp AS /nginx/myapp`

and then all of my applications are down instead of just one.

Is there a "Best Practice" for some setup ike this? Should I `run` the nginx container every time instead of stopping and starting it and then add the links of the apps that are currently running? Should I put nginx on the host level instead of running it in a container?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, links as they stand aren't good enough to solve this problem, at least not beyond a development set-up. I suggest you use a key-value store or something similar to store the mapping.

Comment: You mean, and then create the nginx config on the fly when starting?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You could even take it further and have a process periodically check for liveness and updates. It's basically getting into the problem of service discovery, and you might want to look at things like consul and etcd.

Comment: This is obviously not the answer I was hoping for, makes the container unnecessarily complex. It seems like a workaround for my problem though. Thank you, good luck with the book.

Comment: maybe this could help building such approach: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Comment: Nice, thanks @Mykola. Yeah, another approach is to listen to the events API for containers going up and down and handle it yourself.